# Redirect URL without changing file served to user

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I need to change the url on a website from `/blog/contact` to just `/contact`

But I still need application to serve the content as if the user is still accessing the original URL.

Is it possible within .htaccess to change the URL without changing any of the architecture or logic of the backend? Kind of like a permanent 301 alias?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this with the following rule.

`RewriteRule ^blog/contact/$ /contact [L]`